# Trivial (?) product/series expansions for sine and cosine

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, combinatorial-identities, trigonometric-functions

In an old paper of Glaisher, I find the following formulas:
$$\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}=1-\dfrac{x^2}{1^2}-\dfrac{x^2(1^2-x^2)}{(1.2)^2}-\dfrac{x^2(1^2-x^2)(2^2-x^2)}{(1.2.3)^2}-\cdots$$
$$\cos(\pi x/2)=1-x^2-\dfrac{x^2(1^2-x^2)}{(1.3)^2}-\dfrac{x^2(1^2-x^2)(3^2-x^2)}{(1.3.5)^2}-\cdots$$
These are trivial since the $n$th partial sum is equal to the $n$th partial product of
the product formulas for the sine and cosine

But he also gives
$$\sin(\pi x/2)=x-\dfrac{x(x^2-1^2)}{3!}+\dfrac{x(x^2-1^2)(x^2-3^2)}{5!}-\cdots$$
$$\cos(\pi x/2)=1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^2(x^2-2^2)}{4!}-\dfrac{x^2(x^2-2^2)(x^2-4^2)}{6!}+\cdots$$
$$\dfrac{\sin(\pi x/3)}{\sqrt{3}/2}=x-\dfrac{x(x^2-1^2)}{3!}+\dfrac{x(x^2-1^2)(x^2-2^2)}{5!}-\cdots$$
$$\cos(\pi x/3)=1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^2(x^2-1^2)}{4!}-\dfrac{x^2(x^2-1^2)(x^2-2^2)}{6!}+\cdots$$
Apparently he considers them trivial. If they are, please explain and feel free to
downvote me.

Comment: you're referring to Glaisher's paper [On the Transformation of Continued Products into Continued Fractions](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-5.1.78) --- right?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for including the ref.

Comment: In Nörlund book Vorlesungen über Differenzenrechnung p. 203 speak about Stirlingsche Interpolationsformel, under which appear to be examples the two forms for the cos.  In page 211 there is an expansion for sin pi x / x, but it is not the same as yours.  Maybe there  is more in the book. At least this say what to search.

Comment: @HenriCohen in page 218 there are conditions for the expansion to be valid. Forgotten mathematics

Comment: Are there analogous series stemming from expanding partial products of product formulas for theta functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can derive at least some of these formulas from expansions of $\sin x\theta$ and $\cos x\theta$ as Taylor series in $\sin\theta$,
$$\sin x\theta=x\sin \theta-\frac{x(x^2-1)}{3!}\sin^3\theta+\frac{x(x^2-1)(x^2-3^2)}{5!}\sin^5\theta+-\cdots$$
$$\cos x\theta=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}\sin^2 \theta+\frac{x^2(x^2-2^2)}{4!}\sin^4\theta-\frac{x^2(x^2-2^2)(x^2-4^2)}{6!}\sin^6\theta+-\cdots$$
(For a worked out proof, see this [MSE post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4380218/87355))
Substituting $\theta=\pi/2$ gives the $\sin(\pi x/2)$ and $\cos(\pi x/2)$ series. Substituting $\theta=\pi/3$ gives slightly different series than in the OP...